# Set swig options with consolidate

Tags: node.js, swig-template

I'm currently using swig with consolidate and it works fine :

```
app.engine('server.view.html', consolidate['swig']);
```

Now, I would like to tune [swig options](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/api/#SwigOpts), and for example change the default value of autoescaping.

Any idea of how I can do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found ! If I interact directly with the swig object, it works. I added :

```
var swig = require('swig')
```

Then :

```
app.engine('server.view.html', consolidate[config.templateEngine]);
swig.setDefaults({
  autoescape: false
});
```